# Meaning of に起こす

Tags: meaning, words, particles, particle-に

I'm reading a manga in which often 起こす is used with に, in situations like this:

> 次は工場用に　こいつをパターンに起こす

The characters just finished making a test piece for a shirt, and the speaker is saying to the other characters that sentence; I kinda understand it ("Next we have to copy this [shirt] on a pattern / to make a pattern out of this shirt"), but I'm wondering about the form に起こす.

I tried looking on [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%99), and the third meaning (To create, to produce) kinda seems to fit, but I tried looking in the examples and no one uses に, instead they use を. Then I tried [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%99), which again always uses を, with the sole exception of a single example of meaning 8 (速記や録音の音声などを文字化する。また、文章を書いたり文書を作ったりする。「講演の録音を原稿に—・す」); this is specific for transcribing audio or shorthand, though, so I'm not sure this is the meaning in which it's used in the sentence above (and や seems to point to a non exaustive list, so they could just be examples).

My guess is that the meaning 8 applies, maybe as an extension, but with the underlying idea of copying/transcribing/putting something onto something else, so こいつをパターンに起こす would mean something like "Copy it in a pattern", or (I think in a more natural English) "Make a pattern out of this", the basic idea being to look at the shirt they made and use it to make a copy on paper to be used as pattern.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically right. The 起こす refers to the action of putting something into something else in another form, where some sort of transcription or extraction is involved. Practically, it is used in a narrow context as given in the examples: transcribing sounds into texts. When drafting a prose, it is 原稿を起こす; When there is a original, （e.g. インタビューを）原稿に起こす.

A related word is [テープ起こし](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%97/#jn-150658) （= テープを文字に起こす）. I don't think other source of sounds are used in this way (no mp3起こし). Also, 文字起こし （=文字に起こす） can be used in the same sense.

---

[パターン](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3/#jn-176548) here is used in the following sense.

> ３ 洋裁などで用いる型紙。「―オーダー」

which are [things like these](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%80%80%E6%9C%8D&sxsrf=APq-WBv65gX_KMrSH0E59dEnhV6W2bWlmg:1647645732894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivvf_U5tD2AhXZyYsBHdDrA1gQ_AUoAXoECAMQAw&biw=1338&bih=781&dpr=1.1).